# Gnome3 defaults to fallback

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, gnome-shell

I'm new to Arch Linux and I've installed Gnome3. When I start it, it just offered me a fallback mode, that's not bad, I mean I've been using it for several days. But I'd like to try the standard mode now.

My graphics card is ATI(HD 6470M & 6520G) and I've installed `xf86-video-ati`
but Gnome3 just failed to fallback mode...

And after I typed `gnome-shell --replace`, it shows:

```
failed to create drawable
(gnome-shell:1497): Clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to initialize Clutter: Unable to select the newly created GLX context
Error window manager: Unable to initialize Clutter.
```

Also there's `nomodeset` in this file: `grub.cfg`, and if I remove it, I could just get a black screen...

I really don't know what should I do... how can I solve this problem? Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KMS (Kernel Mode Setting) is enabled by default in kernels after 2.6.33 (you should be on Kernel 3.0 if you are running an up-to-date Arch). So you should remove `nomodeset` from your kernel line (the option in `grub.cfg`). This will prevent the Clutter error.

In order to start X successfully, make sure you have added `radeon` to your MODULES array in `/etc/rc.conf` ( you will need to rebuild your initramfs image if you have to add it).

There is more detail, including troubleshooting options on the [Arch Wiki ATI page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ati).

For newer cards like yours, you might want to use the [catalyst driver](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI_Catalyst).

If you must disable KMS use `radeon.modeset=0`

Comment: i've tried the catalyst driver, but it has crushed several times and the topbar won't appear... so... do i have to use catalyst driver, if i want to use gome3?

Comment: and when i'm using xf86-video-ati, seems i've to use radeon.modeset=0 to disable KMS or i'll just get a black screen...

Comment: xf86-video-ati works well with Gnome3 for the majority of ATI cards. Yours may just be too recent. You could try this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=971794#p971794

Comment: GNOME 3 Shell uses a helper application /usr/libexec/gnome-session-is-accelerated (which returns either 0 or 1) to try to determine whether a graphics card supports hardware acceleration or not is determined by.  You could try replacing this application with a script that simply returns true.